# Использование NSUndoManager в Swift

Tags: swift

Не получается сделать функцию отмены последних действий в приложении на OS X. В Objective-C это реализовано так:

```
// Функция отмены добавления новой записи
- (void)insertObject:(Person *)p inEmployeesAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
NSUndoManager *undo = [self undoManager];
[[undo prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex:index];
[employees insertObject:p atIndex:index];
}
```

У меня есть класс `Person` в котором объявлены две переменные `name` и `raise`. Так же есть массив `employees`, с которым связан Array Controller, через который я  добавляю и удаляю новые записи. Соответственно для отмены удаления записи используется следующий метод:

```
// Функция отмены удаления записи
- (void)removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
NSUndoManager *undo = [self undoManager];
Person *p = [employees objectAtIndex:index];
[[undo prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] insertObject:p inEmployeesAtIndex:index];
[employees removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Тут все работает хорошо. Я попытался перенести эту реализацию на Swift и у меня Undo и Redo не активны в меню редактирования. Вот, как я это реализовал:

```
//Функция отмены добавления новой записи
func insertObject(person: Person, inEmployeesAtIndex index: NSInteger) {
    let undo = NSUndoManager()
    undo.prepareWithInvocationTarget(self).removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex(index)

    employees.insertObject(person, atIndex: index)
}
```

И метод для отмены удаления:

```
// Функция отмены удаления записи
func removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex(index: NSInteger) {
    let undo = NSUndoManager()
    let person = employees.objectAtIndex(index) as! Person
    undo.prepareWithInvocationTarget(self).insertObject(person, inEmployeesAtIndex: index)
    employees.removeObjectAtIndex(index)
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение своего вопроса

```
//Функция отмены добавления новой записи
func insertObject(person: Person, inEmployeesAtIndex index: Int) {

    // Add the inverse of this operation to the undo stack
    let undo: NSUndoManager = self.undoManager!
    undo.prepareWithInvocationTarget(self).removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex(index)
    if !undo.undoing {
        undo.setActionName("Add person")
    }

    employees.insertObject(person, atIndex: index)
}

// Функция отмены удаления записи
func removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex(index: Int) {
    let person = employees[index] as! Person

    // Add the inverse of this operation to the undo stack
    let undo: NSUndoManager = self.undoManager!
    undo.prepareWithInvocationTarget(self).insertObject(person, inEmployeesAtIndex: index)
    if !undo.undoing {
        undo.setActionName("Remove Person")
    }

    // Remove the Employee from the array
    employees.removeObjectAtIndex(index)
}
```